# AppCenter builds on iOS never finish installing

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I've abandoned trying to make a Push enabled build at this point simply to get something working

I've cleaned literally every certificate off my account and off my Mac

Starting from scratch I have

- Requested certificate authority
- Uploaded to Apple Developer
- Generated certificate (first developer, then ad-hoc distribution)
- Generated profile (first developer, then ad hoc)
- Downloaded both
- Generated P12
- Uploaded to AppCenter

I've made developer builds and ad-hoc distribution builds

They build without error in App Center

The installation device certificate installs fine

The app simply never loads

Please can someone give me the simplest example possible that ought to work, this is driving me insane

Comment: Can you install directly from your Mac?  Is it only App Center builds that give you problems?  Have you checked the device logs?

Comment: Yes I can install from the same machine to the same device no problem.

Comment: @Journeyman1234 Having a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/ios/uploading-signing-files) , which steps you think maybe the problem. And you can show the error screenshot in queston .